# Dialogflow follow-up intents not resolving correctly when running botium tests

Tags: automated-tests, dialogflow-es, botium-box

I have created a Dialogflow agent with several follow-up intents. The agent works and resolves to the correct intent when testing the agent manually on the Dialogflow console. However, when I run a Botium test, the agent behaves differently, specifically when it reaches the first set of follow-up events, and it does not resolve to the correct intent. Has anyone experienced a similar issue? I appreciate any info on the issue.

UPDATE:
I was able to recreate the same issue described above with one of dialogflows pre-build agents (coffee-shop). This agent also makes use of follow-up events, where the program resolves to the correct intent from a yes or no answer given by the user. Once again, the dialogflow console convo is successful, but the agent behaves different at these points testing with botium.  I am using the botium official docker image (botium/botium-cli) to run the scripts and help rule out any incorrect configs. I am getting assertion errors, but not run-time errors from the program. I provided screenshots of the same agent conversation from dialogflow, and botium ran as a script and emulator: [dialogflow console convo output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/msALs.png), [botium convo script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aK4Dh.png), [botium script assertion error output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oPjTY.png),  [botium emulator output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xfcCI.png). Let me know what else i can provide. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you update your question to show the tests in question that are failing and any other diagnostic information shown when they fail? The more information you can provide, the better chance we'll have of helping you diagnose the issue.

Comment: please attach logs and configs. if you dont want to share it here, you can use contact form on our web site botium.at

Comment: I can reproduce this problem and will try to find a solution.

Comment: I found a quick workaround for successful botium tests by setting all context lifespan to a value of 1. This is not ideal, but it got me through this hurdle. I suspect botium is not handling contexts with >1 lifespans correctly.

Comment: This has been fixed with this PR: https://github.com/codeforequity-at/botium-connector-dialogflow/pull/21 (not part of the releases yet, but you can install the latest build manually)